# Need to remove data from a substring

Tags: sql-server, substring, data-cleaning

I haven't the foggiest how to remove a substring from my column, I have been looking here for a few days and everyone seems to want to remove data from the end not the beginning.

Column data: `/data/data/data.com --data=nameiwant2keep`

Column name: `column1`

Table name: `table1`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you expect the column data to look like after the substring operation?

Comment: you should show several examples of `before` and `after` data, that cover all standard and any strange cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to keep just the `nameiwant2keep` part, and there won't be any other parameters in the column data, you can search for the index of the `=` sign and take the substring from the next character to the end of the string:

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    column1 = SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX('=', column1, 0) + 1, LEN(column1))
```

Try this for proof:

```
DECLARE @column1 varchar(max) 
SET @column1 = '/data/data/data.com --data=nameiwant2keep'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@column1, CHARINDEX('=', @column1, 0) + 1, LEN(@column1))
```